# Current Rating of Stepper Shield Ground Wire

Tags: current, dc, stepper-motor, shielding

I have a 2 phase bipolar stepper motor;
https://catalog.orientalmotor.com/item/all-categories/20mm-pkp-series-2-phase-bipolar-stepper-motors/pkp214d06a-2

Its 4 power wires are wrapped in a shielded shroud, for EMC compliance reasons.
The shielded shroud is then grounded to the control board (which provides motor power).
Does it sound sensible and safe to assume the max current rating for the shield grounding wire would be no more than the max current per phase for the motor? If not, what are the key parameters you would consider to determine the current rating of the grounding wire, in terms a mechanical engineer would understand.
Appreciate any advice.

Comment: With your drive arrangements, does the shield conduct any of the motor current? If not, and assuming <50V drive voltage as is true with most steppers, the shield isn't a safety matter and I can't see why it should be fault current related. It's only about EMC (containing radiated emissions) and its current rating is not critical.

Comment: Hi Brian, your assumptions are all true. The inducted (I think this is the right term) current will always be a very small fraction of the phase current then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shield is exactly that, a shield, it is not technically a conductor. It is basically a flexible metal case around your cable.

Under normal circumstances, there should be no current passing through the cable shield.

However, in some situations where chassis grounding is being used, or the ground at either end of the cable is at different levels, it IS possible to have significant currents passing though the shield. This should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I had misunderstood its purpose. Appreciate the input, this makes more sense now.

Comment: @JamesIzzard thanks for the personal thanks... always nice to hear, but remember that is what the voting /accepting buttons are for ;)